# How to plot line graph in R with years as x-axis and y-axis as count?

Tags: r, plot, dataset, import-from-csv

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Year    AL    AK    AZ    AR    CA    CO
1993    135   153   113   157   718   516
1994    218   154   184   185   845   465
1995    482   846   683   682   863   863
```

I want to plot line graphs over time, so x-axis is year, y-axis is the count and each line would be a state.
How can I get the year to show up on the x-axis?

I've been running this:

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", header=T)
plot(data$AL, type="l")
par(new=T)
plot(data$AK, type="l")
.....
```

Except with what I have above, the x-axis is "Index" but I want it to be year.

Comment: `?matplot` can be useful. Try `matplot(x=df[,1], y=df[, -1], type = "l")`. Also read `?par` and play around to find a solution.

Comment: the narrow answer to your question is that you should use `plot(data$Year,data$AL)` etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treat your data as time series and the solution comes very easy:

```
df <- read.table(text="Year    AL    AK    AZ    AR    CA    CO
1993    135   153   113   157   718   516
1994    218   154   184   185   845   465
1995    482   846   683   682   863   863", header=T)

time.series <- ts(df[, -1], start=1993, end=1995)

plot(time.series, main="Toy example")
```

which produces

[image]

If you want a single panel, then:

```
plot(time.series, main="Toy example", plot.type="single", col=1:6)
```

[image]

You may want to read `?legend` to get know how to put legends on plots.

Comment: Thanks. Hmm. I can plot single but the multi-panel is giving me trouble -- error in plotts(x = x, y = y ... ... cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple". The real data set has 50 states + DC and start is 1993 end is 2009. What's going on?

Comment: There's nothing wrong, you cannot plot more than 10 series using multi-panels, that's what the error message says.

Answer (score 2):

You may also try to read your data straight to a `zoo` object, which then can be plotted.

```
library(zoo)

z1 <- read.zoo(text = "Year    AL    AK    AZ    AR    CA    CO
1993    135   153   113   157   718   516
1994    218   154   184   185   845   465
1995    482   846   683   682   863   863", header = TRUE)

plot(z1, xlab = "Year")
```

[image]

If you want to plot all lines in the same panel, use `plot(z1, plot.type = "single", col = 1:6)`.