# creating line graph in R combining multiple vectors

Tags: r

I have some problems with a relatively easy task. I am trying to get a line graph of the following data:

Replicate   L0  L3

ZeaA4   0   11

ZeaA5   0   11

ZeaA6   0   14

ControlA15  0   6

ControlA17  0   6

ControlA19  0   6

BrassicaA50 0   12

BrassicaA51 0   12

BrassicaA56 0   14

The dataframe I am reading in, NA is removed and kept blank. 
The line graph should have the number of days (the measurements) on the x axis and on the y axis the three stages L0-L2-L3. (Basically I want to visualise the slopes to get an idea of the growth rate and differences).

With ggplot I failed, but I found the following solution (treating it as time series: [How to plot line graph in R with years as x-axis and y-axis as count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19595520/how-to-plot-line-graph-in-r-with-years-as-x-axis-and-y-axis-as-count)). However:

> df <- read.table("data3.txt", header=T, sep="\t")
>   df
>     ZeaA4 ZeaA5 ZeaA6 ControlA15 ControlA17 ControlA19 BrassicaA50 BrassicaA51 BrassicaA56
>   1     0     0     0          0          0          0           0           0           0
>   2    11    11    14          6          6          6          12          12          14
>   larval.stage <- ts(df[, -1], start=L0, end=L3)
>   Error in ts(df[, -1], start = L0, end = L3) : object 'L0' not found

Is there a solution to get an easy graph as this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, but I don't see any L2 column or the number of days in your data set. What does `str(df) ` show? It may be that your data is not being read correctly. Create the data set and use `dput(df)` to include the data set in your post.

Comment: I realize that my question is a bit cryptic. I simplified the dataset to make it slightly easier, but did not change the text with it. (But couldn't succeed even with a simple task like this.

Comment: I realize that my question is a bit cryptic. I simplified the dataset to make it slightly easier, but did not change the text with it. (But couldn't succeed even with a simple task like this.
In the end I want to have a line for every replicate (ZeaA4, ZeaA5 etc..) with different slopes (all starting at 0 for time point L0, but ending at number of days X for L3). (And with intermediate points for L2 etc.).
When trying this I run into the same error as above.

Comment: O and forgot. str(df) seems to be fine:
> str(df)
'data.frame': 2 obs. of  10 variables:
 $ Replicate  : Factor w/ 2 levels "L0","L3": 1 2
 $ ZeaA4      : int  0 11
 $ ZeaA5      : int  0 11
 $ ZeaA6      : int  0 14
 $ ControlA15 : int  0 6
 $ ControlA17 : int  0 6
 $ ControlA19 : int  0 6
 $ BrassicaA50: int  0 12
 $ BrassicaA51: int  0 12
 $ BrassicaA56: int  0 14

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the column for number of days on x-axis, and neither is L2 seen so I'm assuming you've shown only a part of the dataset. I see you are also getting object L0 not found. Get rid of the sep ='\t'.
For the sake of understanding lets put the column "Replicate" on x-axis -

```
df <- read.table("data3.txt", header=T) 
plot(df$Replicate,df$L0,type ="l", ylim = c(0,15))
lines(df$Replicate,df$L3,type = "l")
```

Similarly for L2, you can add a similar 'lines function' as mentioned above. You get a plot like this.
[image: Line plot for dataset asked in question]